# Improving performance using pokerstove library

Tags: c++, poker

I've recently started using the pokerstove library (https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove) and managed to perform some basic hand / equity evaluations with it. Unfortunately, as soon as I tried to write a bit more computationally expensive programs, I ran into massive performance issues that couldn't figure out how to deal with.

As an example I've provided the following program that calculates the average equity that the hand Ace-6 of spades has against a completely random hand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <pokerstove/penum/ShowdownEnumerator.h>

int main() {

using namespace pokerstove;
using namespace std;

CardSet completeDeck;
completeDeck.fill();
cout << "The whole deck has " << completeDeck.size() << " cards" << endl;

CardDistribution anyTwo;
anyTwo.fill(completeDeck, 2);
cout << "There are " << anyTwo.size() << " two card combinations"  << endl;

CardDistribution holeCards;
holeCards.parse("As6s");

ShowdownEnumerator showdown;
vector<EquityResult> result = showdown.calculateEquity(
    vector<CardDistribution>{anyTwo, holeCards},
    CardSet(""),
    PokerHandEvaluator::alloc("h")
);

double shareRandom = result.at(0).winShares + result.at(0).tieShares;
double shareHand   = result.at(1).winShares + result.at(1).tieShares;
double total       = shareRandom + shareHand;

cout << "A random hand has "  << shareRandom / total * 100  << " % equity (" << result.at(0).str() << ")" << endl;
cout << "The hand As6s has "  << shareHand   / total * 100  << " % equity (" << result.at(1).str() << ")" << endl;

}
```

Once it finally stops, it outputs

```
The whole deck has 52 cards
There are 1326 two card combinations
A random hand has 40.0942 % equity (804780676 36223609 0 0)
The hand As6s has 59.9058 % equity (1220344506 36223609 0 0)
```

On my machine (which I admit isn't particularly fast) this computation takes roughly 4 minutes! Since this seems unreasonably long I belief that there has to be something wrong (performance-wise) with this implementation.

Hence, I would be very grateful if anybody could point out to me where I'm doing something wrong / inefficient.

I would suspect that one can reduce the number of random hands from 1326 to 169 (due to equivalence of suits), but I didn't find a way to implement that behaviour.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use a profiler to see the bottleneck.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's pretty clear, that the computation for the `calculateEquity` function takes the vast majority of the time. I just don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: @Gabriel How do avoid that?  Use a profiler.  And do not guess where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Now I did: I've kept `valgrind`running for more than a full hour now and I don't see that finishing anytime soon - it's probably hopeless this way... In general, I'm looking for advice on how to better use the `pokerstove` library. Since I'm pretty new to the topic there are probably a couple of people around here who a much better way of working with this library.

Comment: @Gabriel - `valgrind` is not a performance profiler.  Assuming you're running on Linux, `perf` is more what you want:  https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

Comment: I suggest to ask directly to people of the library how to use it the best way.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for the clarification and the link. I now used `perf` for the analysis. It returned the result
`227972,151184 task-clock (msec) # 1,000 CPUs utilized;443 context-switches # 0,002 K/sec;45 cpu-migrations # 0,000 K/sec;183 page-faults # 0,001 K/sec;0 cycles # 0,000 GHz;0 stalled-cycles-frontend # 0,00% frontend cycles idle;0 stalled-cycles-backend # 0,00% backend  cycles idle;0 instructions;0 branches # 0,000 K/sec;0 branch-misses # 0,000 K/sec`
Unfortunately, due to my limited knowledge on this topic, I do not know how to interpret these data. Can you give me a hint on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: that's how fast it goes.

A longer answer is, this version is a general purpose evaluator capable of evaluating any kind of game.  It does not do anything fancy like caching results, precomputing large tables, using suit isomorphisms, or anything else.